# What could be so wrong with VPS server that MySQL workbench launch would take 12 minutes?

Tags: performance, hosting, vps

I got a VPS account that is supposed to be pretty performant ( they guarantee 2 2ghz CPU cores and 1.5gb ram). However for a couple of days its been crawling in perforamnce. I recorded a video where I launch Workbench and it is taking 12 minutes on server (through remote desktop)

I am running 3 monitoring tools so you can see that CPU/memory are fine.

Here is the video:  [slow performance video](http://www.vimeo.com/27938342)

I really need help , can't get much help from  hosting support currently.
Should I just run away? It wasn't always like that, but I had performance issues fairly often I must say, but they usually lasted maybe for 15 minutes and not 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was indeed some severe problems with HDD IO. After big discussion they moved my VPS on another machine and there IO is times times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does your VPS has any sort of CPU or I/O guarantees?  If your paying less then $100/mo, you almost certainly don't.  Your likely sharing the hardware with many other active containers or VMs.  It could be either CPU or I/O (disk or network) contention with other users.  In general, running databases on VMs for anything other than trivial use is a formula for bad performance.

Comment: yeah they say they guarantee  2 2 Ghz Cores and use HyperV Core so I am thinking that should mean I got those guarantees, cost is 70$ mo

Comment: You can burst to 4 cpus at Linode and it has had good numbers in performance reports.

Comment: You may be getting those guarantees.  CPU != I/O.  For example, AWS' VMs are excellent for compute but disk I/o (AWs EBS) can be painfully slow.